# Efficient way to find number of objects under a S3 prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I can think of these solutions:

- Cloudwatch Bucket metric is good but that's only available at the bucket level.
- S3 List (with prefix) is time consuming for millions of objects.

Is there any other efficient and cheaper way?

Comment: Does it have to be in real time? Could you run S3 inventory once a day to get such a list?

Comment: @Marcin not real time. I just want to find this on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

- Call `ListObjects()` (with pagination) to obtain the current list, or
- Use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV/ORC/parquet file listing all objects, or
- Create your own database (eg in DynamoDB) that keeps track of objects and create AWS Lambda functions that are triggered whenever objects are created/deleted to update the database

Comment: S3 inventory is good with hundreds of millions of objects and it was cheap as well.